# How to check if a xml value is null in Flex?

Tags: php, apache-flex

```
$output .="<keyword>".$_POST['keyword']."</keyword><name>".$row['url']."</name><occur>".$row['occurrences']."</occur><queryTime>".(substr($end_time-$start_time,0,5))."</queryTime>";
}
```

I want to check in Flex, if the value of name is null or not. I tried for these, but i am not getting any alert when the node value is empty.

```
event.result.attribute("name").value < 0

event.result.attribute("name").length < 0

event.result.loginsuccess.name = ""
```

Can anyone Help me out, Here is my flex code below.

```
if(keyword.text == "") 
{ 

Alert.show("Please enter the search term");
    } else if(event.result.attribute("name").length < 0) {
            Alert.show("No search Results"); } 
else { 
                subtitle.text = "Search results for " +  event.result.loginsuccess.keyword[0];
                        query.text = "query executed in " + event.result.loginsuccess.queryTime[0] + " Seconds";
            }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this

```
event.result.loginsuccess.name[0] == null
```

why?

because when you call a child directly on XML it always returns as XMLList so we should check that if XMLList has any child. The [0] (first index) tries to return the first child if exists othwerwise returns null

in your example it should be :

```
if(event.result.name[0])
{
...
}
```

because the name is an element not attribute, if name was attribute then it should be

```
if(event.result.@name[0])
{
...
}
```

i hope it helps

**EDIT**

pls try this way

```
if(keyword.text == "") 
{ 

Alert.show("Please enter the search term");
    } else if(!XML(event.result).name[0]) {
                Alert.show("No search Results"); } 
else { 
                        subtitle.text = "Search results for " +  event.result.loginsuccess.keyword[0];
                                        query.text = "query executed in " + event.result.loginsuccess.queryTime[0] + " Seconds";
                }
                }
```

Comment: I am not getting any alert message, when the name field is null... its not checking i think so.

Comment: I tried with your code, i get the alert message now but the problem is when there is a result for a particular keyword then also it shows No search results. 

Its not going to else condition itself.

Comment: your xml output is wrong, a xml should have one element (root element). start your output with <root> or any name you want and close the root tag at the end of output

Answer (score 0):

Can also check for empty string e.g.

```
if(event.result.name=="")
{
}
```